# Triggering lesser reflows in JavaScript - How to edit elements in cloned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reflow

I have this HTML structure:

```
    <p id="lorem">
      <span class="part" id="n01">L</span><span class="part" id="n02">o</span><span class="part" id="n03">r</span><span class="part" id="n04">e</span><span class="part" id="n05">m</span> <span class="part" id="n06">i</span><span class="part" id="n07">p</span><span class="part" id="n08">s</span><span class="part" id="n09">u</span><span class="part" id="n10">m</span>
    </p>

​<h1>Click Me</h1>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and this JavaScript code:

```
​arrRed = ["#n01", "#n04", "#n05", "#n09"];​​​​​​​​​
arrBlue = ["#n02", "#n07", "#n08"];

$("h1").click(function(){

    $.each(arrRed, function( i, v ){
        $(v).addClass("red");
    });

    $.each(arrBlue, function( i, v ){
        $(v).addClass("blue");
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FF2Dr/

When the `h1` is clicked, certain letters get a certain color. The problem with that is the performance, I trigger too much reflows/repaints.
​
In another question someone told me to use `parent.cloneNode(true)` and `parent.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, parent)`. So I clone the elements, change them and but them back in place, triggering only one reflow.

So I cloned the parent element:

```
var doc = document;
var lorem = doc.getElementById("lorem");
var clone = lorem.cloneNode(true)
```

But how do I have to proceed now? I somehow have to modify the elements in `clone` and then replace them, but using `$.each` again to edit them does not seem to be a good idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/FF2Dr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("h1").click(function(){
    var lorem = $("#lorem"),
        clone = lorem.clone(true);
    clone.children().filter(function() {
        return $.inArray('#' + this.id, arrRed) != -1;
    }).addClass("red").end().filter(function() {
        return $.inArray('#' + this.id, arrBlue) != -1;
    }).addClass("blue");
    lorem.replaceWith(clone);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FF2Dr/8/)

Create a [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), filter the children of this new cloned element twice to apply the classes and finally replace the old element entirely with the new one.

Or, if you prefer, using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) while iterating over the arrays:

```
$("h1").click(function(){
    var lorem = $("#lorem"),
        clone = lorem.clone(true);
    $.each(arrRed, function(i, v) {
        clone.find(v).addClass("red");
    });
    $.each(arrBlue, function(i, v) {
        clone.find(v).addClass("blue");
    });
    lorem.replaceWith(clone);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FF2Dr/9/)

Comment: @Sven No problem, I just simplified the syntax in the 2nd example, even though the first one should have a higher performance. `=]`